# Outlook categories misery

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have switched from the usage of folders to the usage of categories only.

When I rename a category in Outlook it turns out it doesn't rename the category, but replaces the category of the mails that are kept off-line in the ost-file with the new category.

This means the items on the server still have the old category.
First you see: "We couldn't find what you were looking for" but also: "Find more on the server".
Then this server view turns out to be limited to 250 items and the others are just invisible, you have to use a magic box.

By choosing Search Tools | Ádvanced find | Advanced tab
one can select Field|Categories is exactly ... which gives
"We didn't have anything to show here" without the option to also search on the server.

I tried to have all items in the local ost-file by setting "Mail to keep offline" to All under Account Settings | E-mail Accounts | E-mail | Change | Server Settings.

It doesn't change anything.

Does überhaupt any form of intelligence exist in the Outlook team of Microsoft or am I assuming something ridiculous?

Comment: Can you assign the renamed color category to an email message from OWA? Categories are stored in your mailbox, the changes should be synced to the server. You may also try recreating the .OST file to see the result.

Answer (score 1):

It works like that: when you rename the category in the Master Category List, Outlook starts processing all items that have this category assigned (you can see this in the Outlook main window's status bar). It can take some time to process items. Then the synchronization process starts and it can take much more time to complete. So, you need to have your Outlook running for some time to let the sync to finish. After that you'll find all required items.

Comment: Does that synchronization process also update the categories on server side items that are dated beyond the OST sync limit setting?